# Redirecting base url only using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to redirect only the base url to an external site.

For instance, I want `example.com` redirected to `anotherdomain.com` but I don't want `example.com/path` to be redirected.

So far, `example.com/path` redirects to `anotherdomain.com/path`. :(

**EDIT :**

First, thank you for the help! example.com now redirects to another.com without affecting the children paths of example.com.

However, ideally, `m.example.com` won't redirect to `another.com`. So it's really just `example.com` redirecting to `another.com`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your `DocumentRoot`. I am assuming that you are hosting only one domain on the server.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.
RewriteRule ^$ http://anotherdomain.com [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava! and thinking monkey! I didn't put the rewrite condition

Comment: actually no. because i have a mobile site. so right now, if i go to m.example.com, it redirects to anotherdomain.com (but i don't want it to do that)